# Where is the samples setting for the Cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Where can I adjust the amount of samples Cycles uses?

Comment: Render settings. Are you using Cycles?

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ  He tagged Cycles.

Comment: Just double checking, as it has been an issue before

Comment: Why do people downvote questions like this. Yeah, you can spend 20 minutes trying to find the answer in the manual, or 10 minutes clicking through everything and guessing and checking, or you can spend 25 seconds looking it up on S.O. If it takes me 2 minutes to answer someone's question that they could answer themselves in 10, there's a substantial net time savings between me and that one person. And if a bunch of other people find the answer useful, that's a boat load of time saved. Please, folks, don't be annoyed at someone for trying to save themselves and others a little time.

Comment: Ok, the guy sounds frustrated, which isn't really appropriate for this kind of  Q&A reference, so I've submitted an edit to eliminate that.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the number of samples for Cycles under the *Sampling* rollout of the *Render* Properties panel.  The *Render* spinner adjusts the number of samples used for the final render, and the *Preview* spinner adjusts the number of samples used for viewport rendered mode.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I love the red marker. Did you just ms paint?