# Glass material not transparent in cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, glass

After following Andrew Prices' tutorial for coffee and a doughnut to the coffee part, I find that my cup seems to be frosted glass in the render while looking transparent in non-rendered views.

Is this caused by reflections in the environment, or have I got the material wrong somehow?  Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Welcome! I think that's fine, you just need to *up the samples* for the viewport (Preview): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47137/where-is-the-samples-setting-for-the-cycles-render and wait a bit longer :) After a few minutes it will resolve into a transparent cup.

Comment: Figured it out, I had the light positioned almost overhead making odd reflections in the cup.  Re-positioned light = no more frosted glass.  =)

Comment: Makes no sense to me, but if so please write an answer and accept it for people having the same issue @OKH

Comment: @OKH hmm, that didn't fix the problem, at least for me...

Answer (score -1):

Get glass material from: http://blendermada.com/materials/?engine=cyc&category=glass&keyword= Is it Cycles or Eevee? Refractions and reflections in Eevee are not so great. Use Cycles if is a still photo.

Comment: Why we should use this material? Any advantage compared to the principled shader?

Comment: It was Cycles, but I think I fixed the problem.  Thanks for the response!